# How to have a Test suite that tests from different modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am writing up tests for my automation framework. 
I have a couple of questions on how to implement the situation that I am in:

1. I have multiple modules with unit tests in it and I need to execute them through the test suite. Is there a way that I can add tests from multiple modules into a  different module that will act as my test suite. Not able to figure how if that is possible or are there any alternate methods. The test modules may sometimes reside in a different directory. Will that have an impact on their calling from the test suite?
2. There could be a scenario where I need to run multiple test suites as well (depending on what is being passed by the user). So is there a way that I can group different test suites together into another module and have them executed?

Please let me know.

Comment: Could you use traditional module importing? Like `from tests.some_tests import test1, test2`?